# What is the difference between Classic and Integrated pipeline mode in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between classic and integrated in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-in-iis7)

I always wondered what is the difference, advantages/disadvantages of using both.