# Is possible to work with IIS 5.1 and .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, iis

Is possible that the IIS 5.1 works with the .NET Framework 3.5 or higher? I have to build a simple Web page that has access to an SQL Server database quite simple as well (7 tables). I was considering using the LinQ technology for the first time but I think it is only supported with 3.5 version of the framework.

The web page is ASP .NET, for accessing the database what do you recommend aside of LinQ?
Thank you very much in advance!

Julen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to install framework on hosting machine.

IIS mappings for ASP.NET, run the Aspnet_regiis.exe utility:

1. Click Start, and then click Run.
2. In the Open text box, type cmd, and then press ENTER.
3. At the command prompt, type the following, and then press ENTER:
     "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\aspnet_regiis.exe" -i

Than in rightclick on virtual directory >> property >> assign proper framework to it.

check this post of msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx

Comment: Just remember that you still select .NET 2.0 in the ASP.NET tab - you're actually setting the CLR version in here, which didn't change for .NET 3.0 and 3.5.

Comment: I have the framework but it does not appear in the property tab. Do I have to register with the same executable aspnet_registry in the 3.5 framework?

Comment: So basically although the property tells 2.0 it works with the 3.5 capabilities too. I found that the 3.5 version in the directory has not "aspnet_regiis.exe.

Comment: @Julen - this you can also get from net directly or in sdk

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can deploy .Net 3.5 assemblies to a website running under IIS5.1 (e.g. Windows XP).

The versions of .Net you can deploy to the web server are related to the version of the .Net framework you have installed, so as long as you install .Net Framework 3.5 (or 4.0 for that matter) and register ASP.NET with IIS (see [aspnet_regiis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info) then there is no problem.

Of course, there may be certain more advanced ASP.NET features you wished to use that are not available under IIS5.1. For instance, you cannot run ASP.NET in "[pipeline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-in-iis7)" under this version of IIS.

Answer (score 1):

IIS 5.1 came with Windows XP and I don't think you want to run the site on Windows XP.

However, you can develop the site on Windows XP, but then you probably will test it using Visual Studios built-in web server "Cassini".

Comment: It is fine running .Net 3.5 under IIS on XP. Until a few weeks ago, all my ASP.NET development was done in this way. Cassini, IMHO, brings it's own set of problems such as not supporting host headers or SSL which can make it less than ideal for all your development needs (although it can still be useful for some development)

Comment: I am developiong with Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition.

Answer (score 1):

IIS 5.x and ASP.NET 3.5? Yes.

Database layer things: Avoid LINQ-to-SQL, it's deprectated. Your mainstream options will be Entity Framework and NHibernate. My choice is the second one.

LINQ is a query language for collection-based sources and it's used in a lot of scenarios. You need to think about it as a language feature instead of a database access technology - that statement is wrong! -.

Both Entity Framework and NHibernate have LINQ providers, meaning you can query databases with C# and their engine will translate LINQ to Entity Query Language or Hibernate Query Language, respectivelly.

Using LINQ providers or raw ADO.NET, or another OR/M approach would be just an opinion based on experience and personal points of view.

My point of view is any modern application should have database abstraction like an OR/M.

You can try a document database too, which is capable of storing native .NET objects, like RavenDB:

- http://ravendb.net

Using Entity Framework or NHiberante in your project would be a subjective decision because it seems your requirements are limited and both products are great monsters. And RavenDB is just a NoSQL database, and maybe could be more suitable for your needs and you can boost your productivity.

I don't know which are your exact requirements, sorry.