# custom HttpModule doesn't work in vs 2012

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I programmed a custom HTTPModule through implemnting IHttpModule interface.Then i registered it in web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules >
      <add name="AuthHttpModule" type="AuthHttpModule" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

but it's throw an error when i try to access any page

> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated
>   managed pipeline mode.

Note: I'm using VS2012 and C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using **Integrated mode** configure you handlers & modules inside **system.webServer** instead of **system.web**.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>

      </handlers>
      <modules>

      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Or

If you want to use you existing setting you can use **"Classic Mode"** for that.

Comment: I didn't know what is the integrated or classic mode mean, but i tested your code and it's work now! can you give me an explanation ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7