# .NET Web Api - 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

In short words, everything works on local machine but doesn't when deployed to server "A".

I'm sure someting is missing in server "A", but I don't know what it is, and I don't have access there to make changes or proper testing.

So I'm here to aks for help and ideas of what the problem may be so that I can advise the person in charge of server "A", or whatever changes I need to make on my project to make it work there.

That being said, lets talk about my project...

I'm using Web Api, and a route is defined in the global.asax as such:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I'm calling the controllers using Jquery ajax and Kendo UI, as such:

(this is a fake example just to prove the point)

```
read: {
        url: function () {
               return "../api/Member/123";
        }
}
```

Again, everything works great on local server, but when I deploy it, I get for every web api call:

```
404 - File or directory not found.
```

Nothing else.

Things to consider:

- I'm compiling the project with .NET 4.0 framework.
- The website on server "A" is set up to use .NET 4.0 classic (could this be a problem?)
- I don't think MVC 4 is installed in server "A". Does Web Api requires MVC?
- Server "A" is running IIS 7

I added the following to the web.config file, but still get the 404 error:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Download MVC4 to use WebAPI http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Comment: Thanks Icidis, I'm going to see if I can get MVC installed there. I was hoping the problem was something else. What about the .NET version being used, whats the difference between classic and integrated?

Comment: I always use integrated mode. But heres a quick explination. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7

Comment: Installing MVC4 solved it. Thanks. If you create an answer I'll set it as the right one. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download MVC4 to use ASP.NET WebAPI. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Comment: Install it on the server you will be hosting your MVC website.