# Getting the "no type was found that matches the controller named" error message during Ajax Request

Tags: web-services, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I've seen a lot of topics about this, but unfortunately I believe that each case is a different case (or most of them), and I really would love some experts opinion about my case in particular since I cannot make my code work even after reading through some of the other topics.

Situation: I am using an Ajax Request call in jQuery to a WebService method I have created in an WebApi project together with a MVC 4 Application.

My WebService controller class looks like the default, like this:

```
public class AdditionalInfoController : ApiController
{
    //GET api/AdditionalInfo
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    //GET api/AdditionalInfo/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    //PUT api/AdditionalInfo/5
    public void Put(int id)
    {
        string test = "";
    }
}
```

My Ajax Request from jQuery looks like this:

```
function GetAdditionalInfo(obj)
{
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/api/AdditionalInfo/Get",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: obj.id },
        datatype: "json",
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    })
    .done(function (a,b,c) {
        alert("Additional info was retrieved successfully!");
    })
    .fail(function (a,b,c) {
        alert("An error happened while trying to get the additional info!");
    });
}
```

My WebAPIConfig file looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And last but not least, this is my problem: this error message keeps appearing when I browse the returned data variable in .fail and this is what is written:

```
"{
    "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI      'http://localhost:59096/api/AdditionalInfo/Get?id=1'.",
    "MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named    'AdditionalInfo'."
}"
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me as soon as possible. Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Mad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I believe I found out what was going on. I am not entirely certain, but at least my problem got fixed.

Simply by changing what was inside of the "data" field in the Ajax call and I have created a class for an object in the application to hold the whole data. It seems that for some reason the method could not have the syntax "Get(int ID)".

Instead, I did something like "Get( object)" and in the Ajax Request something like "data: obj.ID" and voila, it worked.

Also, since the framework is picky about the names of the REST methods (Get, Post, Put and Delete), I changed the name of the method to something else (like Retrieve or something).

Hopefully this will help someone in the future as well.

Best regards,

Mad

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the error looks like Web API is unable to find the controller 'type' AdditionalInfo. Web API uses assemblies resolver to scan through the assemblies and finds out the controller types. In your case for some reason its unable to find your 'AdditionalInfo' controller probably because it has some problem loading the assembly having this controller.

Try the following and see if there are any errors logged in your EventLog. If you notice any errors then probably you should check if your controllers are present in those assemblies.

- Make the following change in Web.config to view errors in EventLog

  `<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <add name="myListener"
        type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
        initializeData="WebApiDiagnostics" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>`
- In your WebApiConfig.cs, you can do the following:

  ```
     IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver = config.Services.GetAssembliesResolver();

      ICollection<Assembly> assemblies = assembliesResolver.GetAssemblies();

      StringBuilder errorsBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
      {
          Type[] exportedTypes = null;
          if (assembly == null || assembly.IsDynamic)
          {
              // can't call GetExportedTypes on a dynamic assembly
              continue;
          }

          try
          {
              exportedTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
          }
          catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
          {
              exportedTypes = ex.Types;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              errorsBuilder.AppendLine(ex.ToString());
          }
      }

      if (errorsBuilder.Length > 0)
      {
          //Log errors into Event Log
          Trace.TraceError(errorsBuilder.ToString());
      }
  ```

  BTW, some of the above code is actually from the DefaultHttpControllerTypesResolver which Web API uses to resolve the controller types.
  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.cs

**Edited**:
One more scenario where you could hit this problem is if your controller is **nested** inside another class. This was a bug which was fixed later though.

Comment: Thank you Kiran, I will copy the code you supplied and see if I manage to find out anything at all. However, after the code is there and I run the application, where exactly should I look to see the trace? I mean I've used trace before in a previous job but I do not remember how to get to it right now. 
Thanks again!

Comment: You can check the EventViewer's Application event log source...the category should be WebApiDiagnostics...

Comment: Thanks Kiran but I could not do as you've told. I could not decipher your last comment I'm afraid, since I haven't really heard for EventViewer or WebApiDiagnostics before and my google search did not bear fruit. I did fix my problem though, and I'll post it on the answer next. Cheers!

Comment: +1: The code snippet was the key to solve my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812995/all-requests-to-asp-net-web-api-return-404-error. I just had to write the trace into a file because of insufficient privileges to insert into the event log.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have the same parameter names in your methods (int id) as well as in your WebApiConfig/RouteConfig. Try it by changing

```
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "hello";
}
```

to

```
public string Get(int? id = null)
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. However, how would it help solving the issue by merely changing the input parameter to nullable?

Comment: You won't solve the issue, but for me it was helpful that I knew that the parameter causes the problem. (I had exactly the same error because the parameter wasn't the same as in WebApiconfig)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. with me it happens due to a crush in the visual studio (2012). I had the controller file open in visual studio but it wasn't a part of my solution - I couldn't find him in the controllers directory in the solution explorer.

I just added the file to the solution by right clicking on controllers directory => add => existing item.

that fixed the problem for me.

if that doesn't work maybe try to delete the controller and add a new one with the same code . . .