# No routes working, Web API, when published to server

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

When I try to publish my web API to a server I get the following messages

"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"
"No type was found that matches the controller named 'test'."

Everything works on my machine locally. Just trying to get a test controller to work, then work my way up to fixing the other controllers, hence why I have other register routes in my web API.

http://localhost:4159/api/test/1

http://intranetserver/project/api/test/1

here's the controller

```
Public Class TestController
Inherits ApiController

Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String
    Return "value"
End Function
```

here's the WebApiConfig.vb

```
Public Class WebApiConfig

    Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
            name:="DefaultApi", _
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
        )

        '        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
        '    name:="GetVehiclesByDateRange", _
        '    routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{startDate}/{endDate}" _
        ')

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
name:="GetImportersByDateTimeRange", _
routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{startDateTime}/{endDateTime}" _
)

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
name:="GetPagedData", _
routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}" _
)


    End Sub
End Class
```

here's what found in the Global.asax.vb file

```
  Sub Application_Start()

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)

        CorsConfig.RegisterCors(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)

        ''NOTE: Remove the Basic Authentication mechanism below to open the service to all calls. And also comment out any  attributes on Controllers.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(New BasicAuthMessageHandler() With {.PrincipalProvider = New DummyPrincipalProvider()})

    End Sub
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you post the URL that you are accessing to?

Comment: added pseudo urls above, it's an intranet service

Comment: Try routeTemplate:="project/api/{controller}/{id}"

Comment: @ArghyaC did not work

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, Hurray!

For myself it had to do with references not matching what was found on the server.

> "API uses assemblies resolver to scan through the assemblies and finds out the controller types"

thus why I kept getting

> "No type was found that matches the controller named 'test'."

quoted from the following post

[Getting the "no type was found that matches the controller named" error message during Ajax Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673851/getting-the-no-type-was-found-that-matches-the-controller-named-error-message/16674992#16674992)

I had a different version of oracle being referenced then what was found on the server.

Therefore the message you encounter from the Web API may be misleading.

Ensure your .dll references are the same in production as they are on your local machine, among other things.

Hopes this saves you time.