# Global.asax Application_BeginRequest not firing unless physical file exists - 404

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, url-rewriting, global-asax

I use URL rewriting (`HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(...)`) inside Global.asax so the physical files mostly don't exist.
Everything was working fine until I had to remove site from IIS (8.5) and add it again.

And now I get 404 not found for every request. Example `http://localhost/site/article123`
And Global.asax `Application_BeginRequest` event not even firing.

If I however will add empty default.aspx file in folder `/site/article123` everything starts to work fine with URL being correctly rewritten.

Files have not changed, so it's ought to be the problem with IIS configuration.

I do have following inside web.config: 
`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`

Project in IIS is set as an Application with Application Pool .NET v2.0 Classic

**Edit:** 
Same story in IIS 8.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in `Managed Pipeline Mode` set as `classic`. Switching from `classic` to `integrated` by changing Application pool from `.NET v2.0 Classic` to `.NET v2.0` sorted the problem.

As I understood this: in `classic` mode IIS is managing requests, while in `intergated` mode incoming IIS requests map to the ASP.NET engine.

More on pipeline modes: [What is the difference between 'classic' and 'integrated' pipeline mode in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7)

Comment: I have always been in Integrated. 30 pools working and only 1 single pool is not. Then I just changed to classic and back to integrated, now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have ReWrite Module installed under IIS 8.5

Use Web Installer Platform to install it.

Comment: I don't think I need ReWrite module installed. As I have said I use `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(...)` for URL rewriting, and AFAIK it doesn't have dependency on rewrite module. In any case, I do have the ReWrite module installed so it's not the issue.

Comment: There is no such thing as .net v4.5 Pool.  Has anyone got this to work?
I have dotnet 4.0 pool and Integrated and still Application_BeginRequest never fires on IIS8.