# IIS ASP.NET when to use Integrated Mode or Classic Mode?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I use .NET 4, IIS 7.5, Win 7 or Server 2008 R2

On some machines, Integrated Mode works but Classic Mode does not.

The rest of machines, Classic Mode works but Integrated Mode does not.

When writing the user manual, I have to to tell the users to try the 2 modes until the application runs successfully.

Can anyone suggest some concrete ideas to choose which mode to use, rather than trying both?

Comment: Have a look on the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7

Comment: It does not answer, for same app, why some PC works in one mode but some works in another mode.

Comment: Mode depends on the IIS version rather than **PC**, and why above link doesn't answer your query? pls explain

Answer (score 1):

Classic Mode: IIS 7.0 offers the ability to run ASP.NET applications using the legacy Classic ASP.NET Integration mode, which works the same way as ASP.NET has worked on previous versions of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

To choose a pipeline mode, you should start from evaluating your own application.

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis

First run your app in integrated mode, and see if any of the above issues happen. You can switch to classic if you don't want to fix them.

If you experience issues that are machine dependent, not pipeline mode dependent, you need to collect further information and troubleshoot. That's not something simply caused by the pipeline mode, but should be a result of multiple factors. Without further analysis, of course your manual is impossible to write.