# How to check if ETag is set in http header

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, etag

Problem is that this application hosted with IIS 6 and in classic .net pipeline.

Is there any way to know if ETag is set?

Comment: You can check it like this - `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["ETag"]`

Comment: @ArindamNayak no, it said "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."

Comment: @Paul , OP is referring - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7 , this is meant for you only to know difference between those.

Comment: Ah! I see - removed. Apologies @StNickolas.