# Application pool: Integrated or classic

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, application-pool

I want to host my website in IIS7 on my system.
While converting folder to application we have to select an application pool.
There are two application pools are available.**Integrated** and **Classic**.

I am confused which one to select. I have tried both. Both are working.Is there any rule/guideline to use application pool. I have googled this and understood one is using integrated pipelines and the other one is using `ASP.Net_isapi.dll`.

But still confused which one to use. Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer following link 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7

Answer (score 0):

In Classic mode ASPNET works as a isapi (as IIS6 and below). Integrated mode only works in IIS7 and up, and ASPNET works as a part or IIS.
Classic mode is more a compatible mode if you are porting older code.

Answer (score 0):

Classic mode (the only mode in IIS6 and below) is a mode where IIS only works with ISAPI extensions and ISAPI filters directly. In fact, in this mode, ASP.NET is just an ISAPI extension (aspnet_isapi.dll) and an ISAPI filter (aspnet_filter.dll). IIS just treats ASP.NET as an external plugin implemented in ISAPI and works with it like a black box (and only when it's needs to give out the request to ASP.NET). In this mode, ASP.NET is not much different from PHP or other technologies for IIS.

Integrated mode, on the other hand, is a new mode in IIS7 where IIS pipeline is tightly integrated (i.e. is just the same) as ASP.NET request pipeline. ASP.NET can see every request it wants to and manipulate things along the way. ASP.NET is no longer treated as an external plugin. It's completely blended and integrated in IIS. In this mode, ASP.NET HttpModules basically have nearly as much power as an ISAPI filter would have had and ASP.NET HttpHandlers can have nearly equivalent capability as an ISAPI extension could have. In this mode, ASP.NET is basically a part of IIS.

Please check
http://forums.iis.net/t/1153967.aspx?Difference+between+Integrated+and+Classic+mode