# Upload ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I've finally come to publish one of my hobby projects, but the visual studio publish through FTP will not work, FileZilla on the other hand will.

Which left me with the question.. what do i upload?

The whole thing? thats what i tried first, uploading all to the root folder of my webhotel, and all i get is:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Detailed Error Information
Module  DirectoryListingModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler HS-StaticFile
Error Code  0x00000000
Requested URL   http://d32023759.u207.surf-town.net:80/
Physical Path   D:\hshome\hb944222072\domain.dk
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

Things that could have an effect:

The domain is not transfered yet, so i have a temp url?
(only time or stackoverflow will tell me)

The project is 4.5.1 .net and the Server version is 4.0?
(I cant imagine that throwing this error)

The configuration of the website?

For simplicity i have tried uploading a fresh Visual Studio ASP.NET 4.5.1 SPA with Web API template.
 Which i hoped was configured to work out of the box.

And i really feel i've hit a wall googling for any guides or info while googling, so any help, pointers, hints or links to resources are very welcome.

Comment: Is IIS configured to handle a .dk file? (whatever that is)

Comment: domain.dk is the folder containing the website

Answer (score 0):

In my Webhotel management, i had an option to set the ASP.NET Version and its Pipelinemode

Pipeline Modes:

**Classic** [For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode](http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801)

**Integrated** include the System.Web.Mvc assembly and everything just works

Copied from comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7), Thanks to Jon Erickson